# EntityTypeBuilder<> does not contain a definition for 'HasForeignKey'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to specify a foreign key in my ASP.NET Web API Context.cs and thought I could use .HasForeignKey, as per this example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorFK);
```

It doesn't seem to know HasForeignKey, however, and I get Error CS1061

> 'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasForeignKey' and no accessible extension method 'HasForeignKey' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;

namespace RevPiControlAPI.Models
{
    public class ThisContext : DbContext
    {
        public ThisContext(DbContextOptions<ThisContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<RevPis> RevPis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RevPiModels> RevPiModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Modules> Modules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ModuleModels> ModuleModels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<RevPis>().**HasForeignKey**(i => i.RevPiModelId) // 
        }

    }
}
```

Versions I'm on:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeG... {7.0.9}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi        {7.0.13}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore       {7.0.13}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sq... {7.0.13}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.In... {7.0.13}
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore              {6.5.0}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics... {7.0.13}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools {7.0.12}

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the related entity types first. For example something along these lines:

```
modelBuilder
   .Entity<RevPis>()
   .HasMany(e => e.RevPiModels)
   .WithOne(e => e.RevPi)
   .HasForeignKey(e => e.RevPiModelId); add .HasPrincipalKey(e => e. ...) if needed
```

Please check out the [Mapping relationships in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#mapping-relationships-in-ef-core) for options.